# System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The specified network password is not correct

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, office365, csom

When I'm loading a sharepoint of a office 365 tenant using CSOM for analysing I'm getting this error. The password I've used is perfect. My code works fine for all other tenants except one that throws me this error.

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The specified network password is not correct.
       at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
       at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._LoadCertFromFile(String fileName, IntPtr password, UInt32 dwFlags, Boolean persistKeySet, SafeCertContextHandle& pCertCtx)
       at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils.LoadCertFromFile(String fileName, IntPtr password, UInt32 dwFlags, Boolean persistKeySet, SafeCertContextHandle pCertCtx)
       at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromFile(String fileName, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
       at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(String fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
```

Comment: I saw an article where you this line might be causing the issue
`new X509Certificate2(Path, "", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet); `
It needs to be set to MachineKeySet depending on your config

Comment: Can you share that article?

Comment: But my code is already set to  X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet, what is the problem then? @Clint

Comment: not sure, interestingly in your case it happens only on one instance and the others work fine as you say

Comment: Hi Kailash,                      I faced this issue today with certificates, same error that you get.
Are you exporting your certificates, before you create `new X509Certificate` if yes the password that you supply in export method and `new X509 Certificate` must match.